# How to prove that the number of ways that set[n] can be partitioned into disjoint non-empty subsets for even integers is between (n/2)^(n/2) and n^n

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

For any integer n ≥ 1, let r(n) denote the number of different ways that the set [n] := {1, . . . , n}
can be partitioned into disjoint non-empty subsets, the union of which is the entire set [n].

I need to first find r(3) and list all the ways it can be partitioned.

This part I did, r(3) = 5. Since the set {1, 2, 3} can be partitioned in 5
distinct ways: {{1}, {2}, {3}} ; {{1}, {2, 3}} ; {{2}, {1, 3}} ; {{3}, {1, 2}} ; & {{1, 2, 3}}.

Now I have to prove that, for all even integers n ≥ 2:

(n/2)^(n/2) ≤ r(n) ≤ n^n

I'm unsure of how to go about proving this?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to questions with bounds on combinatoric items is to find a collection of $(\frac n2)^{n/2}$ partitions that you can define (even though it does not include all the partitions), then to find a collection of $n^n$ things that include all the partitions of interest (and also some other things).

For the upper bound, there are at most $n$ sets in the partition, so imagine making $n$ buckets and putting each number in one bucket.  Assuming the buckets are different, there are $n^n$ ways to distribute the numbers, each representing a partition.  We will have counted each partition many ways as in your problem the buckets are not distinct, but we will have gotten them all, so $r(n) \le n^n$

For the lower bound, imagine $\frac n2$ buckets and put the numbers $1$ through $\frac n2$ into them, one to each.  Can you find $(\frac n2)^{n/2}$ distinct ways to finish the partition?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it. I never thought about visualising the problem in this way.